# apache httpclient - how to deserialize the response

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm calling an external webservice through HttpClient but I'm facing problem to convert the response that i get. it's a mtom response like this:

--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_5CF5D04EE84169F28B1567408992661
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:5CF5D04EE84169F28B1567408992662@apache.org>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns3:executeResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.myservice.com/bside/plugins/webservices/bigdata/types" xmlns:ns3="http://www.myservice.com/bside/plugins/webservices/bigdata/ws/THCommand/">
            <returnCode>WS000000</returnCode>
            <returnCodeDescription>Processing completed successfully.</returnCodeDescription>
            <systemInfo>
                <ns2:userId>111000</ns2:userId>     <ns2:rsId>619344</ns2:rsId>
                <ns2:sessionId>550211</ns2:sessionId>
            </systemInfo>
            <responseFile>
                <ns2:name>052015_619344_XXXX_YYYY_1567408989171.zip.crypt</ns2:name>
                <ns2:content>
                    <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:urn:uuid:5CF5D04EE84169F28B1567408992663@apache.org"/>
                </ns2:content>
            </responseFile>
        </ns3:executeResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_5CF5D04EE84169F28B1567408992661
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID:

ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½[ï¿½-Oï¿½
ï¿½g/Ü?ï¿½ï¿½sï¿½7ï¿½ï¿½82ï¿½ï¿½!xï¿½Ú«Eï¿½ï¿½|^ï¿½ï¿½.c×‹ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ø¡ï¿½~ï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½CI6ï¿½C_ï¿½ï¿½]oï¿½ï¿½uxï¿½yï¿½lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ó®ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Cï¿½iï¿½ï¿½7cï¿½ï¿½ï¿½<ï¿½ï¿½*ï¿½"-/ï¿½,xï¿½ï¿½lï¿½/0ï¿½Jï¿½(ï¿½d?ï¿½=ï¿½>ï¿½ï¿½BXPï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Tï¿½ï¿½;

I tried to follow suggestions here and there and I came up with this test class https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/branches/2.7.x-fixes/api/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/attachment/AttachmentDeserializerTest.java

But unfortunately it doesnt work or better, I'm forgetting to do something very easy.

Here is some of the code that i wrote for it:

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

```
    String ct = response.getLastHeader("Content-Type").toString().replace("Content-Type: ", "");

    String responseContent = null;

    if (entity != null) {
        responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        MessageImpl msg = new MessageImpl();
        Exchange exchange = new ExchangeImpl();
        msg.setExchange(exchange);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseContent.getBytes());
        msg.put(Message.CONTENT_TYPE, ct);
        msg.setContent(InputStream.class, is);
        AttachmentDeserializer deserializer = new AttachmentDeserializer(msg);
        deserializer.initializeAttachments();
        InputStream attBody = msg.getContent(InputStream.class);

        String attMimeType = msg.getAttachmentMimeType();

        Collection<Attachment> atts = msg.getAttachments();
        Iterator<Attachment> itr = atts.iterator();
        Attachment a = itr.next();
        InputStream attIs = a.getDataHandler().getInputStream();

    }
```

Unfortunately, no elements are present in the collection... my goal is to handle the  elements, but I'm stuck in this conversion.
Thanks in advance for your support.